# what is wrong with this .htaccess and Yii urlManager settings?

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting, yii

I have a yii website under a sub directory e.g

`http://localhost/~username/maindirectory/yiiapp/`

**My htaccess file:**

```
DirectoryIndex index.php index.html index.htm
Options +FollowSymLinks
IndexIgnore */*
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /yiiapp

# if a directory or a file exists, use it directly
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

# otherwise forward it to index.php
RewriteRule . index.php
</IfModule>
```

**protected/config/main.php**

```
...
'urlManager'=>array(
    'urlFormat'=>'path',
    'showScriptName'=>false,
....
```

**The issue:**

let say I accesss :

- step one: `http://localhost/~username/maindirectory/yiiapp/`
- step two: click any link on home page (default yii app) let say `About Us` page
- step three: **`http://localhost/~username/maindirectory/yiiapp/site/page?view=about`**
- step four : click on any on the link (let say same page)
- url will look like : **`http://localhost/yiiapp/site/page?view=about`**

so : all links are accessible as :  `http://localhost/yiiapp/....`  , instead of removing index.php from link the while string b/w `localhost` and base directory is removed .

I tried [this](http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/index.php/topic/25648-clean-urls-its-possible/) already and need the same sort of url on localhost , obviously without using sub domains

please help me fix this .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so  RewriteBase `/~username/maindir/yiiapp` , in .htaccess fixed the issue , not the 
 `'baseUrl' => '/~username/maindirectory/yiiapp'` thing in config/main.php

Here is the full .htaccess file:

```
DirectoryIndex index.php index.html index.htm
Options +FollowSymLinks
IndexIgnore */*
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /~username/maindir/yiiapp

# if a directory or a file exists, use it directly
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

# otherwise forward it to index.php
RewriteRule . index.php
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 0):

Partial answer:

The problem is that you are redirecting to an absolute URL on the same domain.
The URL probably looks like `/yiiapp/site/page?view=about`. However that leads to `http://localhost/yiiapp/site/page?view=about`. You must prepend the website directory relative to the domain (not sure if I expressed properly).

For example, the URL in the `a href` tag should look like `/~username/maindirectory/yiiapp/site/page?view=about` so you must prepend the `/~username/maindirectory` part from somewhere.

Comment: you are right ,but the issue is that the urls are generated using yii framework createurl function or using menu class e.g `$this->widget('zii.widgets.CMenu',array(
   'items'=>array(
    array('label'=>'Home', 'url'=>array('/site/index')),`

Answer (score 0):

Have your tried:

```
'urlManager'=>array(
    ....
    'baseUrl' => '/~username/maindirectory/yiiapp',
    ....
```

http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CUrlManager#setBaseUrl-detail

Comment: not working :( , it keeps adding baseUrl to url on each click